# How to create new assets media for product in shopware 6 using API

Tags: php, shopware6-api

I want to add product with image in database and **add to cart** in **shopware 6** using **API**.
I was stuck at upload image when add product. Product added successfully but not media image.
I create **custom plugin** and upload image through that.

Answer (score 3):

A new media entity needs to be created before they can be referenced for a add product api call. I've added a example to create a media and assign it to a product for you, might need to be tweaked to your specifications:

## Create Empty Media Entity

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "id": "eb85c29df15c41e8abd79552dce73e9a"
}'
```

The uuid needs to be unique and unused in shopware.

## Upload Media Content

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/_action/media/eb85c29df15c41e8abd79552dce73e9a/upload?extension=png&fileName=test' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: image/png' \
  --data 'base64encode(file_get_contents($file))'
```

The image needs to be base64 encoded and can then be transfered as a request body.

## Assign media to product

```
curl --request PATCH \
  --url https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/2a88d9b59d474c7e869d8071649be43c \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "coverId": "eb85c29df15c41e8abd79552dce73e9a"
}'
```

The media can also added via the sync endpoint and/or used as a gallery element.

Answer (score 0):

This post is older, but maybe the next one's coming over finds this helpfull.
I solved this with the bulk payload from the shopware 6 API.

https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/faf8f8e4e13a0-bulk-payloads

async def process_media_entities_with_products_in_bulk(self, media_entities):
"""
Process media entities with associated products in bulk.

```
This method processes a list of media entities in bulk and associates them with products in Shopware.

:param media_entities: A list of media entities containing product and media data.
:type media_entities: list
"""

BATCH_SIZE = 20
tasks = []

upsert_payload = {}

for idx, entity in enumerate(media_entities):
    product_id = entity.get('shopware_uuid', None)
    media_data = entity.get('media', [])[0] if 'media' in entity else None

    # Print an error with data for debugging purposes
    self.output_manager.print_error("Data:", media_entities)

    if product_id and media_data:
        media_uuid = media_data['mediaId']

        # Create the payload for the media object
        upsert_payload[f"media-{idx}"] = {
            "entity": "media",
            "action": "upsert",
            "payload": [{
                "id": media_uuid,
                "alt": media_data['alt'],
                "title": media_data['alt'],
                "mediaFolderId": media_data['mediaFolderId']
            }]
        }

        # Create the payload for the product-media object
        upsert_payload[f"product-media-{idx}"] = {
            "entity": "product",
            "action": "upsert",
            "payload": [{
                "id": product_id,
                "media": [
                    {
                        "id": uuid.uuid4().hex,
                        "mediaId": media_uuid
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }

        # If the batch size is reached or this is the last element
        if (idx + 1) % BATCH_SIZE == 0 or (idx + 1) == len(media_entities):
            tasks.append(self.sync_with_shopware(upsert_payload))
            upsert_payload = {}

# Wait for the results of asynchronous tasks
responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

for response in responses:
    if response and response['status'] != 200:
        # Print an error if the response status is unexpected
        self.output_manager.print_error(f"Error processing the batch. Response status: {response['status']}")
        if 'content' in response:
            self.output_manager.print_error(f"Response content: {response['content']}")

# Print a message upon completion of processing
self.output_manager.print_info("Processing completed.")
```

async def sync_with_shopware(self, payload):
"""
Synchronize data with Shopware.

```
This method synchronizes data with Shopware using a given payload.

:param payload: The data payload to be synchronized with Shopware.
:type payload: dict
"""
MAX_RETRIES = 3  # Number of retry attempts
url = f"{self.base_url}/api/_action/sync"

for attempt in range(MAX_RETRIES):
    try:
        response = await self.http_manager.post_request_with_json(url, payload)

        if response['status'] != 200:
            # Print an error if the response status is unexpected
            self.output_manager.print_error(f"Unexpected status {response['status']} when synchronizing with Shopware. Attempt {attempt + 1} of {MAX_RETRIES}.")
        else:
            # Successful response, break out of the retry loop
            break

    except Exception as e:
        if attempt == MAX_RETRIES - 1:  # Last attempt
            # Print an error for an exception error
            self.output_manager.print_error(f"Error synchronizing with Shopware: {e}")
            self.output_manager.print_error(f"Payload that caused the error: {payload}")
            import traceback
            self.output_manager.print_error(traceback.format_exc())
            return None

# Return as a dictionary instead of `await response.text()`
return {
    'status': response['status'],
    'content': response
}
```

async def upload_image_to_media_with_folder_async(self, media_id, image_path, file_name, folder_id, extension="jpg"):
"""
Upload an image file to a media entity with a specified folder asynchronously.

```
This method uploads an image file to a media entity in Shopware, associating it with a specific folder.

:param media_id: The ID of the media entity to which the image will be uploaded.
:type media_id: str
:param image_path: The path to the image file to be uploaded.
:type image_path: str
:param file_name: The name of the file to be used in the media entity.
:type file_name: str
:param folder_id: The ID of the media folder where the image will be stored.
:type folder_id: str
:param extension: The file extension for the image (default is "jpg").
:type extension: str
:return: A string indicating the result of the upload operation ("success" or an error message).
:rtype: str
"""
url = f"{self.base_url}/api/_action/media/{media_id}/upload?extension={extension}&fileName={file_name.rstrip('.jpg')}&mediaFolderId={folder_id}"
headers = self.shopware_auth_manager._generate_headers(content_type=f"image/{extension}")

try:
    with open(image_path, "rb") as f:
        image_data = f.read()

    response = await self.http_manager.upload_file(url, image_path, headers)

    if response and response.status in [200, 204]:
        print(f"Image {file_name} successfully uploaded to media entity {media_id} in folder {folder_id}.")
        return "success"
    else:
        print(f"Failed to upload image: {response.status}")
        try:
            response_text = await response.text()
            print("API Response Text:", response_text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An exception occurred while fetching response text: {str(e)}")
        raise Exception(f"HTTP Status: {response.status}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception occurred: {e}")
    raise e
```